# Lenovo Android: Problems with switching Flash

Tags: android

I have issues with torch on Lenovo Android A536, where setFlashMode is ignored:

```
    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
    Log.i("Scanner/Light", parameters.getFlashMode() + " " + context.isLight());

    if (context.isLight()) {
        parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
        menu.getItem(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_flash_on);
        Log.i("Scanner/Light", "Flash on.");
    } else {
        parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
        menu.getItem(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_flash_off);
        Log.i("Scanner/Light", "Flash off.");
    }

    parameters = camera.getParameters();
    Log.i("Scanner/Light", "Final: " + parameters.getFlashMode());
```

From logs I can see, that the light is properly turned on/off, however the LED tend to stay in previous state. Even when I see the log `Final` in state `off`, the physical light sometimes stays in state `torch` and vice versa. This does not happen on any other device we have.

Comment: I recommend you to use `getSupportedFlashModes` before set the parameter. would you check the link http://stackoverflow.com/a/23337134 ?

Comment: I can confirm that on each call, FlashMode.TORCH is supported. As I stated, it works, but randomly.