# switching the camera flash to auto mode

Tags: android

i am creating an camera app which will set the flash to auto mode.i am using intent to launch the camera app.I tried the folllowing code but flash remains 
off

```
      Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
                Camera cam = Camera.open();
                Camera.Parameters p = cam.getParameters();
                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);
                cam.setParameters(p);
                cam.startPreview();
                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

                // start the image capture Intent
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: Try these answers on SO- [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23337134/3921977) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6069503/3921977).

Answer (score 0):

Add these to manifest file:

```
android.hardware.camera.autofocus

android.hardware.camera.flash
```

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
```

Comment: it's working,flash switches on but an "can't connect to camera" popup is displAYED

Comment: can't connect to camera means ? can you  elaborate

Comment: i am getting  java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service

Comment: use camera permission.You needed that as you used camera class

Comment: i used camera permission